# My application is started but it ends right away

Tags: elixir

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I've created an elixir application, if I run it with:

```
iex -S mix
```

the application loads the supervisor, the supervisor load the gen_server which connects to rabbitmq and kept listening for messages, but if I run the application with

```
mix app.start
```

or

```
mix run
```

the supervisor is loaded, the worker is started and connects to rabbitmq but it ends right away without any error, sample code:

mix.exs

```
defmodule Sample.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :sample,
     version: "0.0.1",
     elixir: "~> 1.0",
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     deps: deps]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application
  #
  # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information
  def application do
    [applications: [:logger, :rabbit_common, :ssl, :erlcloud, :amqp],
     mod: {Sample, []}]
  end

  # Dependencies can be Hex packages:
  #
  #   {:mydep, "~> 0.3.0"}
  #
  # Or git/path repositories:
  #
  #   {:mydep, git: "https://github.com/elixir-lang/mydep.git", tag: "0.1.0"}
  #
  # Type `mix help deps` for more examples and options
  defp deps do
    [
      {:erlcloud, git: "https://github.com/gleber/erlcloud" },
      {:amqp, "~> 0.1.1"}
    ]
  end
end
```

sample.ex file

```
defmodule Sample do
  use Application
  require Logger

  def start(_type, _args) do
    IO.puts("Starting App")
    Sample.Supervisor.start_link
  end
end
```

supervisor.ex

```
defmodule Sample.Supervisor do
  use Supervisor

  def start_link do
    Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok)
  end

  def init(:ok) do
    children = [
      worker(Sample.Worker, [[name: :sample_worker]])
    ]

    # one_for_one: If one process dies, the supervisor restarts it without affecting the others
    supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

and worker.ex

```
defmodule Sample.Worker do
  use GenServer
  use AMQP

  @exchange    "exchange_name"
  @queue       "queue_name"

  ### Client API

  @doc """
  Starts the worker who consumes rabbitmq messages on exchange @exchange
  """
  def start_link(opts \\ []) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, :ok, opts)
  end

  def stop do
    GenServer.cast(__MODULE__, :stop)
  end

  ### Server Callbacks

  def init(:ok) do
    {:ok, connection} = Connection.open
    {:ok, channel} = Channel.open(connection)
    Queue.declare(channel, @queue, durable: true, arguments: [])
    Exchange.direct(channel, @exchange, durable: true)
    Queue.bind(channel, @queue, @exchange)

    # Register the GenServer process as a consumer
    {:ok, _consumer_tag} = Basic.consume(channel, @queue)
    {:ok, channel}
  end

  # Confirmation sent by the broker after registering this process as a consumer
  def handle_info({:basic_consume_ok, %{consumer_tag: consumer_tag}}, channel) do
    IO.puts("#{__MODULE__} consumer connected")
    {:noreply, channel}
  end

  # Sent by the broker when the consumer is unexpectedly cancelled (such as after a queue deletion)
  def handle_info({:basic_cancel, %{consumer_tag: consumer_tag}}, channel) do
    IO.puts("#{__MODULE__} consumer unexpectedly cancelled")
    {:stop, :normal, channel}
  end

  # Confirmation sent by the broker to the consumer process after a Basic.cancel
  def handle_info({:basic_cancel_ok, %{consumer_tag: consumer_tag}}, channel) do
    IO.puts("#{__MODULE__} consumer Basic.cancel")
    {:noreply, channel}
  end

  # Basic deliverying of a data package
  def handle_info({:basic_deliver, payload, %{delivery_tag: tag, redelivered: redelivered}}, channel) do
    spawn fn -> consume(channel, tag, redelivered, payload) end
    {:noreply, channel}
  end

  # Catches all other messages         
  def handle_info(message, state) do
    IO.puts("#{__MODULE__} handle_info called with #{message}")
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  def handle_call(message, _from, state) do
    IO.puts("#{__MODULE__} handle_call called with #{message}")
    {:reply, :response, state}
  end

  def handle_cast(message, state) do
    IO.puts("#{__MODULE__} handle_cast called with #{message}")
    {:noreply, state}
  end

  ### Implementation

  defp consume(channel, tag, redelivered, payload) do
    try do
      IO.puts("Consuming #{payload}")
      Basic.ack channel, tag
    rescue
      exception ->
        # Requeue unless it's a redelivered message.                                                                                                        
        # This means we will retry consuming a message once in case of exception                                                 
        # before we give up and have it moved to the error queue
        Basic.reject channel, tag, requeue: not redelivered
        IO.puts "Error received: #{exception}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mix run` is the proper command. As with the `elixir` executable, you need to pass `--no-halt`:

```
mix run --no-halt
```

Comment: Great, works as expected. One more question, why does `mix app.start --permanent` doesn't continue working and instead it runs and finish right away?

Comment: Because `--permanent` is not about running permanently, it is about what happens if your application crashes.

Comment: @JoséValim I'm running into the same issue. If I want to compile and run this app qs a deployable binary, what should I do ? I won't have mix or elixir on the other machine, only my binary file.